# CSS long text ellipsis is not configured properly

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

We have the following configuration for long text ellipsis (...):

```
.text-ellipsis {
   display: inline-block;
   max-width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   vertical-align: middle;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

But this feature doesn't seem to work properly, i.e. long text doesn't become shorter with appropriate ending '...'

What can be fixed here?

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try to set some width to the element. You can apply width either in px or in %.
```

```css
.text-ellipsis {
   display: inline-block;
   max-width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   vertical-align: middle;
   white-space: nowrap;
   width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="text-ellipsis">Hello Stackoverlow Users</p>
</div>
```